# Where can i find the .tld files necessary to integrate Tiles in Struts2?

Tags: struts2, tiles, tld

I had hours in Google uselessly, looking for a link to download the following .tld, necessary to integrate Tiles in a Struts project :
    struts-bean.tld
    struts-html.tld
    struts-logic.tld
    struts-tiles.tld
Thank you a lot, in advance :)

Comment: Why? The TLDs are included in the Struts libraries--both Struts 1 *and* Struts 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag libs you mention are for Struts 1, but you have tagged this question as being for Struts 2.  For Struts 2, you can just add the [struts2-tiles-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tiles-plugin.html) to your web app.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, no tld files are needed for Struts2. You all are awsome, guys!

Answer (score 0):

[Struts2 tiles layout Download](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html)

Here is an example , you can download the zip file and customize it accordingly. And the .tld files (i.e. tag library descriptors) for struts2 are kept in the following jar file.

> struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar

Using the above link you can download the jar as well.

Comment: version 2.1.8.1 is old and should not be used.  Make sure to use the latest version, and at least no older than 2.3.1.2 due to critical fixes and improvements.

Comment: Thanks for info rees. Use struts-core-2.3.1.2 jar instead. Rest you download, from the mentioned link.

Comment: Thank you guys for this useful information and for the link :)